# R script - How to detect emoji codes in tweets

Tags: r

I am working with the following data set: https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-user-gender-classification

My goal is developing a `R` script to detect gender through emojis but they are in a weird code that I can´t convert in `UNICODE` that allows linking in one of the emoji dictionaries. I tried `iconv` but it converted to hilo format and I don´t know how to convert it to `unicode`.

I write an example with one of the data set tweets.

```
new <- iconv("Its a double capsule day _Ù÷ã_Ù÷ã 27 varieties of fruit and veg...in a capsule, simples _Ù÷ã_Ù÷ã #fruitandveg #juiceplus #health", from="utf-8", to="UNICODE", "byte")

[1] "Its a double capsule day _<d9><f7><e3>_<d9><f7><e3> 27 varieties of fruit and veg...in a capsule, simples _<d9><f7><e3>_<d9><f7><e3> #fruitandveg #juiceplus #health"
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance